# python counter, python random list

Tags: python, list, counter

In python, how would I get a list to randomly shuffle 1000 times and then return the times it was picked out of the list. For example a dice has 6 sides and I want it rolled 1000 times every time how could I get a return list that shows how many times they were picked?

Comment: your question don't get better by repeating them without knowing what you are doing.

Comment: that is why I'm on here...because I don't know what I am doing. I believe that is why people ask questions...

Comment: But you should have some basic knowledge of the language. If you follow the [tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/index.html) you'll find the loop basics in chapter 4 and 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this (using your dice example):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> from random import choice
>>> 
>>> options = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> 
>>> Counter(choice(options) for _ in range(1000))
Counter({5: 187, 6: 172, 2: 168, 4: 167, 1: 162, 3: 144})
```

In Python 2.x, use `xrange()` instead of `range()`.

---

**Reference:**

- [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)
- [`random.choice`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/random.html#random.choice)

Comment: I'm using python 2.7 any suggestions how I can get this to work     >>>def rollDie(1000):
>myListInOrder= ['1','2','3','4','5','6']
>for i in range(0,5):
>roll=int(random.random(myListInOrder))
.counter=0+1
>counter==counter 
>return counter

Comment: @Nick: It's generally not a good idea to ask relatively complex follow-up question in comments, nor put much code in them. That said, I can't make much sense of either one in yours. Suggest you update your question or, even yet, ask another.